# Executing an .exe I always get "password invalid" when, in another computer, it opens correctly

Tags: password-protection

Periodically I get an exe which I must execute, type in the corresponding password, and then I can retrieve the files I need.

However, ONCE I happened to type in an incorrect password (three times in a row). Ever since, even though I type in the correct password, I cannot open the .exe (message: password invalid, try one more time...)

If I try to open the same file in another computer, I can. How can I fix this?

[image: Print screen of the software]

Comment: Which version of windows are you using?

Comment: Hey @Dez. I am using Windows 7

Comment: @Soph What kind of software protects the files ?

Comment: @HackToHell I added a print screen of the window which asks for the password. Don´t know what software it is... How can i find out?

Comment: Can you right click the file and see in the properties dialog.

Comment: @HackToHell It just says "Application (.exe)". In security it says "this type of file comes from another computer and could be blocked to help protect this computer" (or something like that, I had to translate it)

Comment: @Soph You can check what reg keys or files the app accesses and delete the corresponding stuff  using ProcMon of Sysinternals

Comment: Please excuse my ignorance, but how could I do that?

Comment: It is pretty advanced of you have not done that before but here's the link http://forums.totalwar.org/vb/showthread.php?90267-How-to-Install-amp-Use-Process-Monitor-(ProcMon)-to-gather-data-about-loading-CTD-s